# multiple $this->form_validation->run() not work in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please help me, to validate address. if i select radio button Office, then Office Address required to submit. if i select radio button Residential, then Resi. Address required to submit.

**The radio button name="mailing"**

Here i share controller code:

```
public function addMemberForm(){
if(!$this->form_validation->run('add_form')){
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span style="color:red">','</span>');     
    $this->load->view('admin_panel/add-member');
}
elseif($post['mailing'] == 'office'){
    if(!$this->form_validation->run('office_address')){                        
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span style="color:red">','</span>');
        $this->load->view('admin_panel/add-member');
    }
}
elseif($post['mailing'] == 'residential'){
    if(!$this->form_validation->run('residential_address')){
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span style="color:red">','</span>');
        $this->load->view('admin_panel/add-member');
    }       
}
else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('add_member_msg','<span class="alert alert-success">Member insert successfully</span>');
    return redirect('admin/add_member');
}
```

}

Here i share config->form_validation.php code:

```
$config = [
    'add_form' =>[   
        [
            'field' => 'mailing',
            'label' => 'Mailing Address',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ],
    ],
    'office_address' =>[
        [
            'field' => 'office_address',
            'label' => 'Office Address',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ],
    ],
    'residential_address' =>[
        [
            'field' => 'resi_address',
            'label' => 'Residential Address',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ],
    ],
];
```

Below i share form photo:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution above my question.

Remove office_address and residential_address from config->form_validation.php

You can Validate office and residential address in controller, See below Code:

```
public function addMemberForm(){

$validation_error = array();

if(!$this->form_validation->run('add_form')){
    $validation_error[] = $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span style="color:red">','</span>');
}
elseif($this->input->post('mailing') == 'office'){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('office_address','Office Address','required');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $validation_error[] = $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span style="color:red">','</span>');
    }
}
elseif($this->input->post('mailing') == 'residential'){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('resi_address','Residential Address','required');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $validation_error[] = $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span style="color:red">','</span>');
    }
}


if(count($validation_error)){
    $this->load->view('admin_panel/add-member');
}
else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('add_member_msg','<span class="alert alert-success">Member insert successfully</span>');
    return redirect('admin/add_member');    
}
}
```